# extract data between two substring in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a data in  following format.

```
<br \/>\n-----------------------<br \/>\nPACIFIC TRACKS (PACOTS)<br \/>\n-----------------------<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 1<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: ADGOR 44N160E 47N170E 48N180E 49N170W 50N160W 50N150W<br \/>\n           50N140W ORNAI<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: ORNPDX ORNSEA ORNYVR<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nACFT LDG OTHER DEST--ORNAI SIMLU UPR TO DEST<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/ADNAP R591 ADGOR<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 11<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: LEPKI 38N160E 38N170E 36N180E 32N170W THOMA<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: THOHNL<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-1000 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nTRK 12 NOT AVAILABLE<br \/>\nATM CENTER TEL:81-92-608-8870<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/AVBET OTR11 LEPKI<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 14<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: EMRON 39N160E 42N170E 42N180E 42N170W 41N160W 40N150W<br \/>\n           39N140W 38N130W ALLBE<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: ALLSFO ALLLAX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nTRK 15 NOT AVAILABLE<br \/>\nATM CENTER TEL:81-92-608-8870<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/MOLKA M750 ANKIX Y891 IGMIS Y57 POROT OTR11 AVBET OTR9 EMRON<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 2<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: KALNA 43N160E 46N170E 46N180E 46N170W 45N160W 43N150W<br \/>\n           42N140W 40N130W SHENU<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: SHESFO SHELAX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/ADNAP OTR5 KALNA<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 3<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: EMRON 41N160E 44N170E 44N180E 44N170W 43N160W 41N150W<br \/>\n           40N140W 39N130W DACEM<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: DACLAX DACSFO<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nATM CENTER TEL:81-92-608-8870<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/AVBET OTR9 EMRON<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: J<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: BOXER FULMR FASEL 51N140W 55N150W 57N160W ONEOX NULUK<br \/>\n           NANDY NATES NIKLL NYMPH NUZAN NIPPI<br \/>\nWEST FL..: 300 320 340 360 380 400<br \/>\nENTRY....: SFOBOX LAXBOX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0500 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nRTS-XIT\/NIPPI R220 NANAC<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: K<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: BOXER ENDAW ZANNG 49N140W 53N150W 56N160W 58N170W OGGOE<br \/>\n           OFORD OBOYD ONEIL OPAKE OLCOT OPHET OGDEN OMOTO<br \/>\nWEST FL..: 300 320 340 360 380 400<br \/>\nENTRY....: SFOBOX LAXBOX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0500 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nRTS-XIT\/OMOTO R580 OATIS<br \/>\n<br \/>\n
```

I am trying to extract the data in between

TRACK....:x  and ending of TRACK x(thats means starting of other TRACK like TRACK n)
x, and n can be any number or alphabet.

Thanks
I tried many way to extract  i used this expression also but no use

```
TRACK....: X<br \\\/>(.*)<br \\/\>\\n<br \\/\>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/TRACK\.{4}:.+?(?=TRACK\.{4}:|$)/gm
```

[Will match](https://regex101.com/r/FRgxrF/1) all substrings started with `TRACK....:` and up to the next `TRACK....:` or the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```js
/TRACK\.\.\.\.: \w+<br \/>([\w\W]*?)<br \/>\n<br \/>$/gm
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/8Nd2nw/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  TRACK                    'TRACK'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ': '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <br                      '<br '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w\W]*?                 any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), non-word characters (all
                             but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <br                      '<br '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  <br                      '<br '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                       '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  >                        '>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

**JS code**:

```js
const string = `<br \/>\n-----------------------<br \/>\nPACIFIC TRACKS (PACOTS)<br \/>\n-----------------------<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 1<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: ADGOR 44N160E 47N170E 48N180E 49N170W 50N160W 50N150W<br \/>\n           50N140W ORNAI<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: ORNPDX ORNSEA ORNYVR<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nACFT LDG OTHER DEST--ORNAI SIMLU UPR TO DEST<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/ADNAP R591 ADGOR<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 11<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: LEPKI 38N160E 38N170E 36N180E 32N170W THOMA<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: THOHNL<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-1000 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nTRK 12 NOT AVAILABLE<br \/>\nATM CENTER TEL:81-92-608-8870<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/AVBET OTR11 LEPKI<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 14<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: EMRON 39N160E 42N170E 42N180E 42N170W 41N160W 40N150W<br \/>\n           39N140W 38N130W ALLBE<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: ALLSFO ALLLAX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nTRK 15 NOT AVAILABLE<br \/>\nATM CENTER TEL:81-92-608-8870<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/MOLKA M750 ANKIX Y891 IGMIS Y57 POROT OTR11 AVBET OTR9 EMRON<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 2<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: KALNA 43N160E 46N170E 46N180E 46N170W 45N160W 43N150W<br \/>\n           42N140W 40N130W SHENU<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: SHESFO SHELAX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/ADNAP OTR5 KALNA<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: 3<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: EMRON 41N160E 44N170E 44N180E 44N170W 43N160W 41N150W<br \/>\n           40N140W 39N130W DACEM<br \/>\nEAST FL..: 290 310 330 350 370 390 410<br \/>\nEXIT.....: DACLAX DACSFO<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0700 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nATM CENTER TEL:81-92-608-8870<br \/>\nRTS-ENT\/AVBET OTR9 EMRON<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: J<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: BOXER FULMR FASEL 51N140W 55N150W 57N160W ONEOX NULUK<br \/>\n           NANDY NATES NIKLL NYMPH NUZAN NIPPI<br \/>\nWEST FL..: 300 320 340 360 380 400<br \/>\nENTRY....: SFOBOX LAXBOX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0500 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nRTS-XIT\/NIPPI R220 NANAC<br \/>\n<br \/>\nTRACK....: K<br \/>\nWAYPOINTS: BOXER ENDAW ZANNG 49N140W 53N150W 56N160W 58N170W OGGOE<br \/>\n           OFORD OBOYD ONEIL OPAKE OLCOT OPHET OGDEN OMOTO<br \/>\nWEST FL..: 300 320 340 360 380 400<br \/>\nENTRY....: SFOBOX LAXBOX<br \/>\nVALID....: 06\/28-0500 TO 06\/28-2100<br \/>\nCOMMENTS.:<br \/>\nRTS-XIT\/OMOTO R580 OATIS<br \/>\n<br \/>\n`
const regex = /TRACK\.\.\.\.: \w+<br \/>([\w\W]*?)<br \/>\n<br \/>$/gm
const matches = [...string.matchAll(regex)]
console.log(Array.from(matches, m=>m[1]))
```